# Ubuntu is running in low graphic mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card

I am using ubuntu 11.04 on dell insprion 1545. But I am facing a problem that when I start laptop a message shows on the black screen that says

> Ubuntu is running in low graphic mode. Your screen, graphic card and input device setting could not be detected correctly, you will need to configure these yourself

I have read that there is a file Xorg.conf that contain the graphics card information. I have also use the command

```
sudo cp /etc/x11/xorg.conf /etc/x11/xord.conf_backup
```

but its not working.

Comment: `xorg.conf(5)` will be useful to you. Good luck -- getting the configuration _just right_ can be pretty tedious. I'm glad I haven't needed to configure mine in a few years.

Comment: Did X _ever_ work on this machine? Did it break recently?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just log out and choose "Ubuntu (classic)" from the login screen?